# CSS Width 100% not active on this page?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this page: http://rebar.ecn.purdue.edu/LTAPmobile%20-%20Copy/Helpers/News.aspx

Hows come width:100%; doesn't work here?  The content doesn't shrink with the window width.

Thanks in advance

Comment: shrink the width of the window, as if you were on a mobile phone (this is being built for mobile phones). the text doesn't wrap/shrink with the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me to....

Then I read your comment its for mobile devices....

Unfortunately the domain was down or could not be found when i tried to load it on my mobile?

Anyway maybe this page can help you?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/

Its possible that the META TAG

```
<!-- mobile check -->
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width">
```

could need modifying to make sure it works on mobile devices properly. Maybe the link above can help point you in the right direction.

## UPDATE

Initially the page would not load at all on my mobile device, So I copied your code and changed saved it to a temporary file and uploaded it to my server, initially it still gave the 404 error.

So I modified the META TAG which I mentioned above from the original to the same as listed below:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

I also modified the links point to other resource files which started with with ../ to fully qualified pathnames, after doing that and re-uploading it to my server I was finally ABLE to view the page on my mobile device (Huawei G300 ASCEND using Opera Mini browser)

When I rotated my mobile phone from a LANDSCAPE to PORTRAIT position the text was re-aligned and formatted correctly complete with lines of text under each other (re-flowed).
I viewed it Opera Mini and the factory browser built into the phone - the factory browser supports html5 though I'm not sure of the make/brand of the browser.

Comment: thanks for the link, but i'm looking for more of a reason why this doesn't work. So you're saying when you shrink your window width, all the content still fits?

Comment: Hello again, NO What i'm saying is I tried it on my desktop and it loaded okay. Then I re-read your comment (that it is for mobile devices) So I re-tried it on my mobile and the page failed to load with the message SERVER ERROR IN '/' APPLICATION and then it states below that... "The resource cannot be found" HTTP 404